# Time Scheduling in Navision with Timer

Tags: timer, timer-jobs, navision

I am facing some problem regarding running an object , can be form,report etc, automatically depending on the user defined time. Let us say at 6am everyday, a process report should run automatically.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a Solution for me.. This example runs at 7:40, 12:40 and 16:40 each day.

1. Using the Navision Timer 1.0
   NAVTimer    Automation  'Navision Timer 1.0'.Timer
2. Set the Property 'WithEvents' of the NAVTimer to Yes

   Set the Property 'SingleInstance' of the Codeunit, if you using one, to Yes
3. In the On Run Trigger write

> ```
> IF ISCLEAR(NAVTimer) THEN CREATE(NAVTimer);
>
> NAVTimer.Interval := 1 * 60000;  // Important! set to 1 Minute     
>
> NAVTimer.Enabled := TRUE;
> ```

In the Timer Trigger (it appers after you change WithEvents Property to Yes) write

> ```
> sTime := COPYSTR(FORMAT(TIME), 1, 5); // Cut seconds
> sHour := COPYSTR(sTime, 1, 2);
> sMinute := COPYSTR(sTime, 4, 2);
> IF sHour IN ['07','12','16'] THEN
>   IF sMinute = '40' THEN
>     IF NOT CODEUNIT.RUN(CODEUNIT::xxx) THEN;
> ```